# how do i prevent error message that displays confidential data in laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

my laravel is showing the following error message when i uploaded to live server

[image]

so if there is some error, all the confidential data is displayed in live server. i just want to stop this. i know there is some custom messages like

```html
$messages = array(
    'required' => 'The :attribute field is required.',
);

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
```

thats fine, i just want to know if i can stop all error messages like that in the photo and whenever error occurs in live whatever it is just show something like 404 error or something or blank... is there any way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `APP_DEBUG=false` in your .env file.

Comment: let me check ,,,,

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the photo but you can use

```
Try{
//your code
}catch{
//if you want to show your error or something 
}
```

you can use this method to stop the error from showing. It will not do the code in try if it have a error

Answer (score 0):

You can handle **[Error Handling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors)**.
The best way is `try-catch`
Follow the above link for more detail

Answer (score 0):

You can use try catch

```
try{
   //executable code
} catch{
   //error code
}
```

You can also try hide error to Set
    `APP_DEBUG = false`
that are located to .env file. Don't forget to run below commands after changes .env file.

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```